# Counting number like " loop "

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, numbers, counting

I would like to do this like a loop, when finished, again start the counter like loop

**Sample:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4v2wK/226/

```
// Animate the element's value from x to y:
  $({someValue: 40000}).animate({someValue: 45000}, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing:'swing', // can be anything
      step: function() { // called on every step
          // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
          $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
      }
  });

 function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    return val;
  }
```

Comment: And you want it to start at the same 40,000 to 45,000?

Comment: Yes or others numbers could be great too

Answer (score 1):

```
function counter(startVal, endVal) {
    $({someValue: startVal}).animate({someValue: endVal}, {
      duration: 3000,
      complete: function() { counter(startVal, endVal) },
      easing:'swing', // can be anything
      step: function() { // called on every step
          // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
          $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
      }
     });
}
```

Here is an working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2fhf/)

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
(function counter() {
  $({someValue: 40000}).animate({someValue: 45000}, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing:'swing', // can be anything
      step: function() { // called on every step
          // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
          $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
      },
      complete: counter
  }); 
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/4v2wK/227/

Comment: I love synchronous functions :-P